# Getting some message while configure the hub in the command prompt

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to configure hub in the command prompt but getting the following message:

C:\Users\shubham.saraf\Documents\IST\IST\Software>java -jar selenium-server-4.5.0.jar - port 4444 -role hub
Selenium Server commands

A list of all the commands available. To use one, run `java -jar selenium.jar commandName`.

completion    Generate shell autocompletions
distributor   Adds this server as the distributor in a selenium grid.
hub           A grid hub, composed of sessions, distributor, and router.
info          Prints information for commands and topics.
node          Adds this server as a Node in the Selenium Grid.
router        Creates a router to front the selenium grid.
sessionqueue  Adds this server as the new session queue in a selenium grid.
sessions      Adds this server as the session map in a selenium grid.
standalone    The selenium server, running everything in-process.

For each command, run with `--help` for command-specific help

Use the `--ext` flag before the command name to specify an additional classpath
to use with the server (for example, to provide additional commands, or to
provide additional driver implementations). For example:

java -jar selenium.jar --ext example.jar;dir standalone --port 1234

Can anyone suggest me to configure hub?